# custom .bat file, opening multiple tabs and executing a command in each one

Tags: windows, cmd

sorry for rookie custom but I want to make my dev experience easier, so I want to create custom command .bat file in order to open multiple tabs and executing a command in each one (For.example php artisan serve, npm run watch...).

What I tried:

```
C:\Users\GABRIEL\Desktop\custom-command.bat
```

I created .bat file like this:

```
cmd.exe && cd C:\xampp\htdocs\kinshiki && php artisan serve

cmd.exe && cd C:\xampp\htdocs\kinshiki&& npm run watch

cmd.exe && cd C:\xampp\htdocs\ishhiki && expo start
```

But when I execute file I get an error:

```
"C:\Users\GABRIEL\Desktop\custom-command.bat" command is not recognized as an internal or external
```

Comment: Please use the command `START /?` for information about starting multiple processes.

Comment: Do you want these three (3) commands to run sequentially or concurrently?